# What is a Magic-like app?

Tags: android, game, phone

I am searching for an Android app that meets the following requirements.

- Plays similarly to *Magic: The Gathering*
- Allows the user to build custom decks
- Has multiplayer
- **Makes good use of screen real estate**

An app that "makes good use of screen real estate" is one that does not have a lot of "empty space". The following screenshot from *Magic 2015* shows what I do *not* want:

[image]

The table (or "empty space") occupies most of the display and does not provide the user with any value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, looks like you have a couple of options if the screen space is a key factor!

Forgotten Myths ([Link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.AnchoraGames.ForgottenMythsCCG)). Has both co-op and dueling modes. Screenshots look like good use of screen space.

Order and Chaos Duels ([Link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gameloft.android.ANMP.GloftBTHM)). Multiplayer is only PVP by the looks of things.

If you had a tablet, Hearthstone is out soon as well, but indications are that it's only for tablets

Comment: Order and Chaos Duels is the best fit, so far.